# how to add nuxt plugins to vs-code jsDoc type checkings?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, jsdoc, javascript-intellisense

when using plugins in nuxt , we can access them in components and store using `this`

```
export default {
   methods:{
     myMethod(){
        return this.$myNuxtPlugin.doThings()
     }
}
```

to check types with jsDocs in vscode, in `jsconfig.json` i set `compilerOptions.checkJs` to true,

but Vetur/vscode-intellisense cannot detect nuxt plugins types .

the error for above example would be :

```
Property '$myNuxtPlugin' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, { 
myMethod(): Promise<void>; }>>'.Vetur(2339)
```

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @chris unfortunately no i hadn't time for it .